# PHP json_encode data with double quotes

Tags: php, json

I'm using this simple code to transform database query results into JSON format:

```
$result = $mysqli->query("
    SELECT  
        date as a 
        , sum(sales) as b
        , product as c
    FROM  
        default_dataset
    GROUP BY
        date
        , product
    ORDER BY
        date        
");

$data = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

echo stripslashes(json_encode($data));
```

The problem is that if there are double quotes in the data (e.g. in the product column) returned by this query. The json_encode function does not encode the data in a good JSON format.

Could someone help me how to escape the double quotes that are returned by the query? Thank you.

Comment: Can you give an example of what you mean by double quotes?

Comment: Escape them before inserting them in the database? Or using ansi?

Comment: FWIW Re *"The json_encode function does not encode the data in a good JSON format."* Actually, it does. Problems arise when you want to do anything *other* than *parse incoming json directly into a JS object or array, using JSON.parse*. You can prove it works for yourself by reading any json file, created by json_encode, from JS. Yes, there are documented situations where you don't get exactly what you expect (hence various json_encode options). But what you won't get, is a parse failure. NOW, once you start `echo`ing into the HTML text being sent to browser, you have a different situation...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`json_encode` already takes care of this, you are breaking the result by calling `stripslashes`:

```
echo json_encode($data); //properly formed json
```

Answer (score 26):

You will need `htmlspecialchars` instead of `stripslashes` with proper encoding (UTF-8, if your page uses UTF-8 charset) and `ENT_QUOTES` which will escape double quotes preventing data to break. See the code below:

```
echo htmlspecialchars(json_encode($data), ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
```

Answer (score 4):

Example with a simple array with `double quotes` string value.

```
$yourArr = array(
    'title' => 'This is an example with "double quote" check it'
);

// add htmlspecialchars as UTF-8 after encoded
$encodeData = htmlspecialchars(json_encode($yourArr), ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');

echo $encodeData;
```

**Result:**

```
{"title":"This is an example with \"double quote\" check it"}
```

**[According to PHP Manual:](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php#100565)**

> That said, quotes " will produce invalid JSON, but this is only an
>   issue if you're using json_encode() and just expect PHP to magically
>   escape your quotes. You need to do the escaping yourself.

Comment: share manual just for indicate either json valid or invalid... there are so many options aviallable in manual for escaping quotes.. @Steve

Comment: Yes, sure - but you quote a paragraph that simply isnt there. Maybe it did in 2011...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, PHP json_encode wouldn't "**escape double**" quotes, we need to escape those manually in this super simple way-

```
array_walk($assoc_array, function(&$v, $k) {
  if(is_string($v) && strpos($v, '"') !== false) {
    $v = str_replace('"', '\"', $v);
  }
});
// After escaping those '"', you can simply use json_enocde then.
$json_data = json_encode($assoc_array);
```

Answer (score -1):

to encode the quotes using [htmlspecialchars:](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php)

```
$json_array = array(
'title' => 'Example string\'s with "special" characters'
);

$json_decode = htmlspecialchars(json_encode($json_array), ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
```

Answer (score -2):

You can done that using base64_encode and base64_decode

To store in database first convert it to base64_encode and stored into database and if you want that data then you can decrypt that data using base64_decode

```
$var['cont'] = base64_encode($_POST['data']);
$dd =  json_encode($var['cont']);
echo base64_decode ( json_decode($dd) );
```